# Why can't we use base class reference to a derived class object if inheriting privately?

Tags: c++, class, oop

It might be a stupid question, but I'm wondering. If we're inheriting publicly - public methods of base class are becoming public methods of the derived class. If we're inheriting privately - public methods of base class are becoming private methods of derived class. So:

If we're making two classes, like:

`Testing1` (which inherits publicly) and `Testing2` (which inherits privately):

```
class Testing1 : public std::string
{
private:
    std::string a;

public:
    Testing1(std::string str = "Null") : a(str) {};
};

class Testing2 : private std::string
{
public:
    Testing2(std::string str = "Null") : std::string(str) {}
};
```

Why is it that we can make a base class reference in the class where we're inheriting publicly:

```
Testing1 a;
std::string* ptr1 = &a;
std::string& ref1 = a;
```

But we can't use the base class reference to a derived class in the class where it's inherited privately?

```
/* Can't do this */
Testing2 b;
std::string* ptr2 = &b; // -> error
std::string& ref2 = b; // -> error
```

Comment: Don't kid yourself. It's not a stupid question, and you asked it very well.

Comment: I'm gonna guess that it's because the copy constructor in string is now private in your privately derived class and thus can't be called by clients.

Comment: The "Can't do this" code CAN be done in either a member function of `Testing2` or a `friend` of `Testing2`.     Not being able to do it in other places is the point of `private` inheritance - other code (that is neither a member nor a `friend` of `Testing2`) is not permitted to access a `private` base of `Testing2`.   That includes preventing a conversion of a `Test2 *` to a `std::string *` (or conversion of a `Test2 &` to a `std::string &`) as you're seeing, since that would sneakily allow untrusted code to access a `private` base.

Comment: It's actually because the constructors of the base class of `std::string`  (`std::base_string`) become unavailable when it is inherited privately. Peter is spot on in explaining the reasoning behind this behavior in the specification.

Comment: @dmedine No it isn't. `std::string* ptr2 = &b` does not require any constructor invocations.  It is because the fact of inheritance is private.

Comment: Suppose you can do `std::string& ref2 = b;`, then you can also call say `ref2.append("xyz")` which does exactly the same thing as `b.append("xyz")` but `append` is private in `b`. So your private methods become "private but you can easily call them anyway" methods, which is rather useless.